# Adding an array of HKWorkouts to UserDefaults

Tags: swift, healthkit

Is there anyway to add an array of HKWorkouts to UserDefaults or do I have to save the array in core data?

Comment: UserDefaults dosent support all types, and because of that you will have to convert it into a double (or string I guess?) and save it to the userDefaults. Once you retrieve the data from userDefaults you will of course have to convert it back to the type you're using. That would be my guess, but maybe there is another way. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HKObject` and its subclasses conform to `NSSecureCoding`, so you can convert an array of them to `Data` using `NSKeyedArchiver`. See the [NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedarchiver) documentation for more details.